# what exact permissions should I grant to devs on a test box

Tags: oracle, user-permissions

I recently set up a Oracle 12.0 box for devs to test code on. What permissions should I grant them to do their work?

Comment: Grant what they need. For pure development environment I would recommend DBA role.

Comment: To grant dba privileges would violate company policy.

Comment: In this case prepare yourself to become "donkey-worker" who copy/paste the commands from the developer they cannot execute by themselves due to missing privileges. Perhaps the developers will install an Oracle database on their local computer and thus violate company policy and most likely also Oracle license conditions.

Comment: Grant them SELECT and CREATE SESSION (CONNECT) at the beginning. If they complain, give them more - perhaps insert, update, delete, create table, create view, create procedure, create trigger, create sequence  ..... please see [the full list of privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21642/privileges.htm#TTSQL341)

Comment: Please post full information in the original question: "To grant dba privileges would violate company policy". If you are bound by various company policies that we don't know about, it's going to take a long time to work this out

Comment: Privileges for testing and for developing code are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Dev should not have access to test environments at all. 
****most they should have is read #user-permissions

Comment: Good point. If it's specifically a test environment, the privileges should match those available or planned for production.